# Adding descriptions of courses I've taken to my resume

Tags: resume

I'm a college student applying for summer internships. I've taken several classes that are relevant to the internships I am applying for, and I would like to mention this in my resume.

The way I've seen it done in other resumes is to have a section titled "relevant courses" and to list a few courses relevant to the specific position. However, I would like to include a one or two sentence description of each course, explaining what I learned from the course. Is this something that people would recommend doing? And could someone give me an example of such a resume so I can see how it would be formatted?

Comment: Probably better to list the courses very briefly, list the skills you have acquired  briefly, and get into details when you get to the interview. If they want to know, they'll ask. Keep the resume focused enough that people actually read it and see and remember the most important points.

Comment: Are they asking for a cover letter ? You could provide examples of the things you learned in the class, and how they proved useful, in the cover letter. If you have no professional experience, you could expand in the resume, but your general education (school+field) should be enough info for any employer.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a CV is to sell yourself.

As you are a college student include as much information into that page (not a page) to enable you to get your foot in the door.

So include details about courses that you have done and what you have learned.

Also note that the CV is a basis for an interview. The person giving the interview likes to have something in common to talk about - and that is you!

Good luck

PS: There is no right or wrong here

Comment: ^this, I've seen way too many students fresh out of school who send a resume that describe only the courses they did without any explenation. Technology changes, courses change content every year. writing down what the course contained and what your best experiences are from it is essential for the company to know. Especially since you don't have any working experiences yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not include course descriptions on your resume.  Your resume should probably follow this general outline.

- Name and contact information
- Education/School attended and degree obtained (No coursework here, if your GPA was over a 3.0 then include it otherwise omit it.)
- Recent achievements (Contests won, awards received, etc.  If none then omit)
- Work Experience (Internships, part-time jobs)
- Extra curricular (Clubs, greek life, student government positions)
- Skills (This is important, if your resume hasn't been passed to the side by now then they are still interested. Don't put BS soft skills like communication, demonstrate those in the interview. Put things that have a concrete output like sales, programming languages, graphic design, etc.  Tailor the skills section to the job you are applying for.)
- Coursework

This question focused on coursework but employers are generally going to evaluate work experience, and extra cirriculars when hiring college grads.  The only thing they are looking at right now is if they should interview you.  The fact that you took ENC 1101 or not will probably not play a factor.  They want to see someone who didn't waste *all* their time in school slugging beers.  That said if you have any achievements such as winning engineering competitions or something of that nature it will really make you stand out.  If you don't have any work experience and you don't have extra curricular's then you have a problem.

Comment: Most lf this answer doesn't address the question at all. He knows the general outline, and work experience is going to be small when he is applying for an internship

Comment: This awnser would be ok if it was addressed to someone who has a rich resume with a lot of experience. if you cut out any description from the courses, you're basically cutting out 80% of the resume. Students dont have working experience to write about. and I doubt the company would want to know about your membership at the local flute club. Therefor, more descriptive courses would be great.

Comment: @Bernhard Funny, because when I read this: "Is this something that people would recommend doing? And could someone give me an example of such a resume so I can see how it would be formatted?"  It make it seems like I directly answered both of the questions..

Comment: @HunterNelson Well, in my understanding he is looking for an example of the section in the resume with the courses.